# Prove a binary operation in a group. Find $a^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G = \mathbb{Q}\setminus\{\frac{1}{32}\}$. In $G$ we have a binary operation $*$ so that  $a * b = a + b -32ab$. 
1) Prove that $*$ is a binary operation on $G$ and that $G$ is a group.
2)Let $n$ be a natural number. Find $a^n = a* a * \cdots* a$ ($n-$times).

--I know how to prove that $G$ is a group but I don't know how to prove that * is a binary operation.

Comment: This is very difficult to read. What do you mean where you're defining G? Do you mean the rational numbers without 1/32?

Comment: Yes! That is what I mean. I tried to edit it but I couldn't. I'm sorry!

Comment: If you can't prove $*$ is a binary operation then, by definition, you *can't* prove $G$ is a group.  That $*$ is a binary operation is one of the things that must be proven to show $G$ is a group. Can you prove that if $a \ne 1/32; $ and $b \ne 1/32$ that $a + b - 32ab \ne 1/32$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a + b - 32ab = 1/32$

$a(1 -32b) = 1/32 - b$

If $b\ne 1/32$ then $1- 32b \ne 0$ so

$a = \frac {1/32 -b}{1-32b}= \frac 1{32} *\frac {1-32b}{1-32b} = \frac 1{32}$.

So.....

...

Perhaps more formally.

Let $a,b \in \mathbb Q$ s.t $a \ne 1/32$ and $b \ne 1/32$

Let $a + b - 32ab = c$.  Then $c \in \mathbb Q$.

As $a(1- 32b) = c - b$ and as $1-32 \ne 0$

$a = \frac {c-b}{1-32b} \ne 1/32$

So $c - b \ne \frac {1-32b}{32}$

$c \ne \frac {1-32b}{32} + b$

$c \ne \frac {1-32b}{32} + \frac {32b}{32} = \frac {1-32b + 32b}{32}$

$c \ne \frac 1{32}$.

So $c \in \mathbb Q\setminus\{\frac 1{32}\}$.

Answer (score 0):

To show that $*$ is a binary relation, you need to show that $a*b\in G,$ for any choice of $a,b\in G,$ then you can show that the group axioms are true. Don't forget that $$-*-:G\times G\longrightarrow G$$ is a function. You'll need to show that this function is well defined. That is, if $a=a^\prime$ and $b=b^\prime,$ then $a*b=a^\prime* b^\prime.$

Bonus, is this group abelian (does $a*b=b*a$ for every $a,b\in G$)?

You should try to post your answer here and then we can help you more.